# 3rd party filters with Kalita Wave or Hario V60

Tags: pour-over, paper-filter

I have been using an Osaka stainless steel dripper for about a year now, and I think the mesh is clogged beyond repair. This results in a very slow, very cold cup of coffee.

So I am thinking of upgrading to something that uses a paper filter. Both the Hario V60 01 and Kalita Wave 155 look great to me. However, I'd prefer to use unbleached compostable filters (possibly *If You Care* brand), but I have not found any info online regarding this kind of filter in these drippers.

Does anybody have experience or tips for using a 3rd party paper filter? What size/shape filter is best? The "specialty" 1st party ones are pricy and typically bleached so they can not be put into the compost.

Edit: Just wanted to edit and say that I have been using cloth filters for the past year from Coffee Sock brand. They work very well, so if anyone stumbles upon this question looking for a similar answer I would recommend something like Coffee Sock.

Comment: Erm, can’t all paper filters be composted? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Stephie sure, but I would prefer brown/unbleached filters. Looking around the internet I see mainly white Kalita Wave filters, so I'm curious if anyone has experience with a 3rd party brown filter

Comment: All paper filters are compostable, even bleached ones. By the time they are used there's no bleach left on them. However there are original unbleached filters for both Hario and Kalita available. In any major online shop and probably most specialized coffee suppliers have them. The If You Care basket filters might work for Kalita. The other filters they have don't work with Hario or Kalita.

Comment: @avocado1 You say there's no bleach left in the filters once they're used...where does it go? It doesn't seem like you want to drink that.

Comment: @ZipZapJ  Think of it like bleaching laundry: After the bleaching step you need to rinse it out. So the bleach is not in the filter or your coffee, but in the water used it the production of the paper. But yes, the bleaching step is purely cosmetic (consumers perceiving „white =clean=better“) and it’s better for the environment to skip it.

Comment: To bleach paper filters either chlorine or oxygen is used. Chlorine is obviously the environmentally more harmful substance. However the amount of chlorine (which is flushed out anyways before brewing) is not harmful. The water you are using probably has more chlorine in it. Oxygen is neither very harmful in the bleaching process, nor is it harmful to you. Hario white paper filters are oxygen bleached for example. Anyways as I've said before as well, all those brands offer non bleached versions of their filters that work just as good. Might have to flush a bit more to get rid of paper taste.

Comment: @Zip Zap J The bleach goes into the air. It evaporates. Chlorine is a gas at room temperature with a boiling point far below 0 degrees (-30 something). So until you use the filters it's all gone.

Comment: @avocado1 wow thanks for the info! I appreciate it. always good to learn . i actually just purchased a CoffeeSock brand kalita wave style cloth filters!

Comment: Perfect, always good to use reusable stuff :)